# How to know why the Pod in OpenShift restarted / crashed?

Tags: openshift

We have a scenario where Pod in an OpenShift is restarting and our application log from the application running inside this pod is not sufficient enough to know the reason for the same.

Is there any log at cluster level which could give some hints why the pod is restarted?

Comment: `oc describe pod <name of pod>` - Shows the event why the pod is restarted

Comment: Using `oc get events` may give clues if caused by an external event such as memory or disk pressure causing eviction, or otherwise running out of memory. Some of that information is also shown by `oc describe` as mentioned.

Comment: @Rinor : i get the below data (i have put the partial data from describe)

      Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       OOMKilled
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Wed, 16 Oct 2019 16:56:40 +0200
      Finished:     Thu, 17 Oct 2019 09:36:54 +0200,   does it says anything helpful ?

Comment: Yeah, OOMKilled, it means that the Memory Resource Limits that you set to the pod were exceeded.

Comment: You need to increase the memory limit. Or if you think the application should not use that much memory it could be an issue with the app. Many programming languages and frameworks try to make use of the most resources for optimizing performance. Google on how to optimize your app for Kubernetes, in matters of Memory and CPU

Comment: Yes, it was indeed issue with the resource allocation.
It was configured properly in the beginning , but at some point resource allocation were modified (we have to see when ), but correcting the resource allocation for pod helped to resolve the issue

Comment: What if the previous-killed pod is already gone, how should I get the reason why it got killed? "oc describe xxxxx" tells me "pod xxxx not found", which sounds reasonable.